# Abort pipeline build if no new commits

Tags: jenkins

In a Jenkins pipeline script, I am using the `checkout` function with class "GitSCM", as in the following example:

```
checkout(
   [
       $class: 'GitSCM', 
       branches: [[name: '*/<branche>']], 
       doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
       extensions: [], 
       submoduleCfg: [], 
       userRemoteConfigs: 
       [
           [credentialsId: '<id>', url: '<url>']
        ]
    ])
```

On the "*Stage View*)" for this pipeline, for each build, the Jenkins UI shows me the number of new commits since the previous build.

I would like to abort the build if there are 0 new commits. How should I do that? Is there a way to get that information from the `checkout` function?